# Draw route via direct gps points

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, google-directions-api

I am trying to draw my car tracking route on maps. I am using Google Directions to make the path from markers exactly on roads. The problem is that directions sometimes think I have used different routes. Please see the picture to get an idea. There are no points in that route and for some reason Directions route the way between waypoints like this... Any ideas how I could sort such problem out ?

[image]

**Update:** I have a ton of gps points at first. I then simplify them using `Douglas-Peucker` algorithm to get 8 points as Google directions only accepts 8.. After that I send them to Google Directions and get the orange route from Google Directions api. Some times the route is OK. But sometimes the google directions get confused and does not paint the road as it should be just.

Comment: How are these markers being added to the maps? Are you sure it's not an alternate route that was colored with the same color as your original route leading to the confusion? Please share some relative code for us to be able to help you better in the scenario.

Comment: From your update, it seems that it might be the alternate route problem that I mentioned. Google Directions API returns more than one route at once and while you might have marked a route, it might still be suggesting another one which comparatively takes a shorter route/time. But without your code, it's hard really to tell what might be the case here.

Comment: Can you tell me what kind of code exactly you would like to see ?